# how do i resolve this project facet in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

In a Java project that was imported into Eclipse, I am getting a marker for a `Faceted Project Problem` that states `Targt runtime Apache Tomcat v7.0 is not defined.`  But Tomcat is not one of the project facets defined in the screen shot below, which also includes the error circled in orange below the Project Facets dialog:

[image]

I do not want to install Tomcat 7 because Tomcat 8 is the server I am using, and Tomcat 8 is defined in the servers tab of Eclipse.  **So how can I resolve this `Faceted Project Problem` without resorting to installing Tomcat 7?**

Comment: still any help comment on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Project Facets there is Server tab,

There you can find Apache Tomcat 7 Unbound.

Go to new button and show the destination where your server got installed.

You will be able to allocate server for your current project.